# How to determine diode will conduct or not

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

Here we had to find the voltage for which the diode will act as a forward bias.

I am a little confused about how do we find whether or not a diode will conduct or not in a network having more than one independent voltage and current source.

What I did was removed the diode, determined the thevnin equivalent voltage across the open terminals after removing the diode. That turned out to be Vi-1 volts.

Am I right ?

Does that mean then that for the diode to be forward biased, Vi-1 volts must be less than zero ?

[image]

Comment: You sure you've drawn that diode the correct way around?

Comment: Yes. I am sure.

Comment: For the 1A produced by the current generator to NOT pass through the diode, the whole 1A must pass through the 1ohm resistor connected to the voltage source. Hence, by Ohm's law, the voltage source must be 1V

Comment: That was when the diode will be reverse bias, right ? And what would be the value of V when diode is forward biased ?

Comment: How to determine the value of Vi for which will the diode be forward biased .

Comment: Assuming a perfect diode (on voltage =0V), anything less than 1V will turn it on.

Comment: Chu. I have a doubt. When there are more than one independent sources(voltage or current) and we have to determine whether or not the diode will conduct, is resorting to thevnin a safe idea ? I mean removing the diode and then finding across the open terminals the thevnin equivalent voltage can help us clearly see if the diode is forward or reverse biased. Am I right ?

Comment: Say the voltage source is 0.9V. The diode is ON, so there is 0V at the top of the diode. The voltage source current will be 0.9A = (0.9 - 0)/1. The current source will draw 1A. Therefore the current up through diode will be 0.1A.

Comment: Whew ! When the diode will be forward biased, wouldn't it instead short circuit the current source

Comment: There's a resistor in series with the current source, so no short circuit. The current source adjusts its terminal voltage to generate the 1A; the voltage source adjusts its current to generate 1V. Both need series resistors (or parallel), generally, or there may be conflict. e.g. a short circuit across a voltage source, or an open circuit current source

Comment: @Chuz Does that mean for finding the voltage below or after which the diode will act as a forward based also we will ignore the resistor in series with the current source because it is too making the diode forward biased by 1v. Can we afford shunning it's presence ?

Answer (score 1):

Note: whenever you have a resistor *in series* with a *current source* you can ignore the resistor for your analysis.

I.e. you can ignore the right resistor and this makes the problem easy:

Hint: Sum of currents into (or out of) any node is 0 (KCL).
So what happens if \$I_{from-left} = V_{src}/R\$ is less than or larger than \$I_{from-right} = -I_{src} = -1A\$?

Comment: True, unless you need to determine the voltage across the current source.

Comment: @Chu: yes, then it matter of course; but not for the rest of the circuit.

Comment: It rather depends on the question. This time it doesn't matter, next time it might.

Comment: Very very often values of current and voltage souces are given and it does not matter what voltages are across the current sources and what current go through the voltage sources. This type of problems make up probably >95% of problems you have to solve in a typical circuit anaylsis class (or in real life). And for the rest of those problems it is still useful as it simplifies the problem and it is easy to go back and eventually find the voltage across (or current through) the resistor that has been ignored before.

Comment: BTW: It is just a trick I consider often very  helpful. If you don't nobody will force you to use it.